# Looping through different excel sheets and find all possible connections using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 excel files with one sheet each. Each excel file looks something like this ~[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oP3WK.jpg)

~[file2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSa9Z.jpg)

I need to loop through the names of the columns and find the connections between the names.

I think I need to add IDs to each name in a separate column, but not sure how to do this in pandas. I'm not sure if this is even the best way to start tackling this issue. I tried this:

```
df = df.assign(id= 
(all_data["index1"]).astype('category').cat.codes)
```

The first column in the 3 excel files contain the same names, but the other columns have different animals in them. I would like to loop through the names in the 3 excel files and when there is a match between a person and an animal, that is stored/counted as 1 connection.
Using the 2 examples provided, there would be one connection: between joe smith and jack smith (they have "dog" and "panda" in common).

For a final result, I think I would like the a list of all possible connections. Any ideas would be helpful!

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your problem correctly but I only see "dog" as the common animal between the two people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would do, however, I have to make a couple of assumptions though.

1) Each sheet is imported as a df correctly

2) You want to see all matches for all animals and all names, thus instead of a list, I'm going to create a dict where the keys are the animals and the names are the values.

```
# Random dfs with random names and animals.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Joe', 'Jack', 'Molly'], 'Animal1': ['Dog', 'Cat', 'Mouse'], 'Animal2': ['Panda', 'Lion', 'Koala']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Ben', 'Bob', 'Blake'], 'Animal1': ['Rhino', 'Panda', 'Dog'], 'Animal2': ['Snake', 'Spider', 'Cat']})
```

We're going to combine the df's into 1 so we have all the names and animals on the same df.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2])

    Name  Animal1 Animal2
0   Joe     Dog    Panda
1   Jack    Cat    Lion
```

Next, were going to make a single column for all the animals. The animals are going to end up in a column called 'value'.

```
df3 = pd.melt(df3, id_vars=['Name'], value_vars=['Animal1', 'Animal2'])

    Name   variable value
0   Joe     Animal1 Dog
1   Jack    Animal1 Cat
2   Molly   Animal1 Mouse
```

Finally, we are going to group by the animals, and make it a dict.

```
df3.groupby('value')['Name'].apply(list).to_dict()
```

Output:

```
{'Cat': ['Jack', 'Blake'],
 'Dog': ['Joe', 'Blake'],
 'Koala': ['Molly'],
 'Lion': ['Jack'],
 'Mouse': ['Molly'],
 'Panda': ['Bob', 'Joe'],
 'Rhino': ['Ben'],
 'Snake': ['Ben'],
 'Spider': ['Bob']}
```